# Problems loading data from a geojson file to a mapbox map

Tags: mapbox

I using this code to load data from geojson file to this mapbox map:

```
var mapTooltips = L.mapbox.map('map-tooltips', 'mapbox.streets')
  .setView([54.00366,-2.547855], 6);

  var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/stations.geojson')
    .addTo(mapTooltips);
```

The problem:

Using this URL from mapbox as a test, the markers appears on the map perfectly

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/stations.geojson

But When I use the same file but from another server, example:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/web-app-cdata/MapaFel/stations.geojson

The markers doesnt appears, doesnt work.

Using the mapbox link:

[image]

Using the S3 link:

[image]

I want to mention, the S3 link have full access. In theory can be accessb anyone

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you are not allowed to load resources(such as geojson files) from external domains. This is referred as making a [cross-origin HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

So, when mapbox-gl tries to load the geojson file([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/bvpmne06/)) from your S3 instance, there's an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/web-app-cdata/MapaFel/stations.geojson. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

You can load the same geojson from the mapbox servers, because Mapbox have explicitly allowed such cross-origin requests, by specifying a response header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

As [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> "The server responds with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * which means
>   that the resource can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site
>   manner. "